# How to add series name in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, charts

For `DataVisualization.Charting`, how can you add a name for each series (or line) like the highlighted part in the image below?
[image]

Comment: Is that not mentioned in this libraries documentation ?

Comment: I can see label for axis and data points, but I couldn't find label for a data line.